# Stacktraces on user instantiated exceptions in Specs2 output

Tags: scala, error-handling, playframework, playframework-2.3, specs2

In our tests, we make extensive use of stubs, some of which create and throw exceptions. I'm finding that just instantiating an exception, is causing a stacktrace to show up when our tests run. This means that there's a large amount of unnecessary and confusing noise, as we don't care about these 'expected' exceptions. I've scoured the internet, but can't find anything about silencing these stacktraces (bare in mind, that *actual* exceptions, thrown elsewhere within the code, or by the framework, I'd like to still show traces for). Is this a common issue and has anyone found a way around it?

Sorry, with example:

```
val t = new Throwable("Expected exception")
val service = new AuthenticationService()(ExceptionThrowingClient(t))
```

Results in a test run with a stacktrace that looks something like this:

```
java.lang.Throwable: Expected exception
at services.auth.AuthenticationServiceSpec$$anonfun$4.apply(ServiceSpec.scala:104) ~[test-classes/:na]
at services.auth.AuthenticationServiceSpec$$anonfun$4.apply(ServiceSpec.scala:103) ~[test-classes/:na]
at org.specs2.mutable.SideEffectingCreationPaths$$anonfun$executeBlock$1.apply$mcV$sp(FragmentsBuilder.scala:292) ~[specs2-core_2.10-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
at org.specs2.mutable.SideEffectingCreationPaths$class.replay(FragmentsBuilder.scala:264) ~[specs2-core_2.10-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
at org.specs2.mutable.Specification.replay(Specification.scala:12) ~[specs2-core_2.10-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
```

Which traces back to the point of instantiation within the spec.

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: Can we see the full stacktrace?